# Splunk query for rarity without AI

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to find a rare user account logons happened in last 7 days on a distinct host.

For example, there are 10 servers in the monitoring, I need to find the user account who never did login before in 7 days but suddenly getting a login from it on any specific host among 10.

Is it possible to make without ML?

`index = "main" and EventCode = 4624 | stats count by host,user | rare limit=1 account dc(hostname)`

Something similar to that.

I tried several queries like using `cluster` and rare multiple hit and trial. But not getting expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp user=* [| inputlookup my_list_of_10_hosts.csv ] earliest=0
| fields _time user host
| stats min(_time) as early max(_time) as recent by user host
| eval early_diff=now()-early
| where early_diff<604800
| eval early=strftime(early,"%c"), recent=strftime(recent,"%c")
```

This will go back through all your data (hence the `earliest=0`), and find all the `user`/`host` combos, noting the earliest and most-recent logins

Then calculate the difference in the `early` time from `now()`, making sure the first time you saw this combo was less than a week ago